# Kuramoto model limit $N\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: complex-systems

Is it possible to say anything about the behaviour of the Kuramoto model for large but finite $N$ based on an analysis of the model obtained in the limit $N\rightarrow\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of the Kuramoto model for large $N$ is not the same as infinite $N$, in certain regimes. Refer to [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28505801) available on [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.07031) if you can't get through the paywall.

Of particular relevance:

> We investigate the scaling properties of the Lyapunov spectrum
>   characterizing the linear stability of the fully locked state, and
>   of the order parameter introduced by Kuramoto [1, 2].   We
>   show that above the locking threshold the largest non vanishing Lyapunov exponent $\lambda_2$ scales like $\lambda_2 \approx (K - K_L)^{1/2} $.  Relating the expression for the order parameter $r$ to the Lyapunov exponents, we show that the order parameter also scales as $r - r_L \approx (K - K_L)^{1/2}$, $r_L \equiv r(K_L) $ being the order
>   parameter at the locking threshold.

And:

> We find numerically that our finite $N$ result is always valid close enough to $K_L$. However, its range of validity $\delta K$ becomes narrower and narrower as $N$
>   increases.

So basically, their large-but-not-infinite model displays a region of unique behavior that gets smaller and smaller as $N \rightarrow \infty$.

The technique they used is also interesting and novel, being based on a unique application of the [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem).

Comment: The authors derive a property of the finite $N$ Kuramoto model and then compare it with a known result regarding the $N\rightarrow\infty$ model. One parameter is 'discontinuous' in the limit. It is interesting, but not exactly what I was looking for. Would you also happen to know a result where the authors find that the $N\rightarrow\infty$ model has some property and then show that this implies that the finite $N$ model has the same property?

Comment: @Asdf, what exactly are you looking for? Why do you need a proof of this kind? The Kuramoto model is a purely theoretical construct and any result about its behavior, whether $N$ is infinite or not, derive from the same constructions.

Comment: I want to prove a property of something that is related to the finite $N$ Kuramoto model, but have only been able to establish it for the corresponding $N\rightarrow\infty$ case. But perhaps that could imply something about the finite $N$ case. I am looking for some inspiration.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to prove, specifically? Perhaps it doesn't hold for finite N.

Comment: I try to prove that a system of differential equations has a stable equilibrium of a certain type. I can do it if I let a parameter in the equations go to infinity. That parameter is similar to the $N$ parameter in the Kuramoto model.

Comment: Perhaps you might get a lot better help if you posted this as a separate question.